# Typo3: change label of "related news"

Tags: typo3

I've a site with Typo3 10.4.36 + News 8.5.2 as extension.
I'd like to personalize the label "Related news" changing it in something other.
It seems not possible from the backend: do you confirm it?
Should I directly update some value in the table related to the news extension?

Thanks in advance for the reply,

Fabiano

I've seen all the backend but found nothing that helps

Answer (score 2):

> Should I directly update some value in the table related to the news
> extension?

No. You'll not find this label in any table. It is located in a language-file of the extension. And, no, you do *not* want to change this file - because it will be overwritten when updating the extension.

TYPO3 offers many possibilities via TypoScript. Your problem can also be solved via TypoScript. For every plugin/extension there's a [`_LOCAL_LANG`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/TopLevelObjects/Plugin.html#local-lang-lang-key-label-key)-property, which allows overwriting language labels.

For EXT:news, the language-file is: `EXT:news/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf`, and the "Related news"-string can be found in [line 30](https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/8.6.0/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf#L30)

```
<trans-unit id="related-news" xml:space="preserve">
    <source>Related News</source>
</trans-unit>
```

You need its `id` for overwriting the label:

```
plugin.tx_news_pi1._LOCAL_LANG.default.related-news = Your text
plugin.tx_news_pi1._LOCAL_LANG.de.related-news = Dein Text
```